# How to test Protected method

Tags: java, junit, easymock, powermock

If the class's constructor is protected, when I do the test case, what can i do to construct an object using EasyMock or PowerMock.this is my source code :

```java
protected TibOperationProxy(SAPApplication sdkApp, String classRef, String getOperationName, String rpcRef,  SAPReqRespImpl sapClient) 
throws MException {
    super(sdkApp, classRef, getOperationName, rpcRef);
    this.sdkApp = sdkApp;
    this.client = sapClient;
}
```

Comment: to create a mock you dont need the constructor of specified class, its EasyMock.createMock(TibOperationProxy.class), or something like this

Comment: but i want to test the construct method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have powerMock whitebox class to help:

```java
TibOperationProxy proxy = org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeConstructor(TibOperationProxy.class, sdkApp, classRef, getOperationName, rpcRef, sapClient);
```

An extra sample, suppose we have the class:

```
public class WhiteBoxTest {
    private final String name;
    private WhiteBoxTest (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And the main method in another class works:

```java
 WhiteBoxTest whitebox = Whitebox.invokeConstructor (WhiteBoxTest.class,
            new Class[] { String.class }, new Object[] { "hello world" });
 System.out.println (whitebox.getName ());
```

Comment: I use the whiteBox proxy=Whitebox.invokeConstructor(TibOperationProxy.class,new Class[]{SAPApplication.class,String.class,String.class,String.class,SAPReqRespImpl.class},sdkApp,classRef,getOperationName,rpcRef,sapClient);but it throws an exception org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: Failed to find a constructor with parameter types: [[Ljava.lang.Class;, com.tibco.sap.adapter.SAPApplication, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.tibco.sap.adapter.services.SAPReqRespImpl]
 at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeConstructor

Comment: You may try to use another method. Useful for testing classes with a private constructor when PowerMock cannot determine which constructor to invoke. `invokeConstructor(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class[], java.lang.Object[]) ` [api doc](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.1/apidocs/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html)

Comment: How to use this method ,what should i write in the second parameter java.lang.Class[]. I used : new Class[]{SAPApplication.class,String.class,String.class,String.class,SAPReqRespIm‌​pl.class}  but not correct.

Comment: yes, that's what I expected. I create a test, and it works. updated my reply.

Comment: Thanks very much Lifecube,Now I can invoke the constructor ,but in the constructor there is an sectence: super(sdkApp, classRef, getOperationName, rpcRef);what can I do to Mock it?

Comment: why you want to mock super? normally when you pass the right parameters, the super should work. And it should be transparent to your test. I think the constructor you invoked, is just to get the instance and to test the other methods.

Answer (score 2):

If the class has a protected constructor,  that constructor is intended to be used only from derived classes. Perhaps the class is an abstract class? Why not just have a test derived class?

Comment: +1 To clarify for the OP, create an inner class in your test that extends the class under test without changing any behavior. This solution is simple and elegant as it does not require any additional testing frameworks and does not mock the class under test which should be avoided in general.